# log4j: RollingFileAppender is not working when file reaches max size, but rolling when restart

Tags: java, log4j

I have below log4j configuration. when file reaches its max size , it is not rolling but when I restart server then rolling is working.

Please let me know what I am wrong in my configuration.

```
<appender name="ALog" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="true" />
      <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
      <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
      <param name="file" value="logs/Log.txt" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>

<root>
      <priority value ="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ALog"/>
</root>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am reading log4j.xml in a main method of java which is called when I start my server

Answer (score 0):

You have to do :

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
<param name="append" value="false" />
<appender-ref ref="file"/>
```

Comment: It did not work. I guess append is true means , it will append the logs when restart the server, otherwise it starts a new file with zero size

Comment: `<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">`
`<appender-ref ref="file"/>`

Comment: <appender-ref ref="file"/>
I added the above line already in my code right..
you can see the below code 
<root>
      <priority value ="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ALog"/>
</root>